# Calling a member method inside a class using a specific instance instead self

Tags: swift

```
class ImAClass {
    init() {}
    
    func wannaPrint(_ str: String) {
        print(str)
    }
    
    func unknow() {
        instanceOne.wannaPrint("hi")
    }
}

let instanceOne = ImAClass()
instanceOne.unknow()  //hi

let instanceTwo = ImAClass()
instanceTwo.unknow()  //hi
```

i don't understand this code in swift, i never seen it in any other language, calling a member method inside a class using a specific instance instead self

In this example i just expected to be able to access members through self

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you didn't see that before is because it's bad code practice.

But what is happening here is that `instanceOne` and `instanceTwo` are 2 global variables.
Therefore they are available from everywhere in your application.

Now that you can access them from anywhere you can access them from inside your class `ImAClass`.

So in that case the method `unknown` is using the instance method `wannaPrint` of the occurence `instanceOne`.

If the scope of `instanceOne` changes you will have a compilation error.

If instanceOne is deallocated your app will crash. But in a validity stand point this code is valid.

You can also do something trickier

```
class ImAClass {
    private let str: String
    init(str: String) {
        self.str = str
    }
    func wannaPrint() {
        print(str)
    }
    
    func unknow(){
        instanceOne.wannaPrint()
    }

}

let instanceOne = ImAClass(str: "Hi")
instanceOne.unknow()

let InstanceTwo = ImAClass(str: "ho")
InstanceTwo.unknow()
```

This will have the same result as before even tho the text assign to each instance is different. It's because we use the method `wannaPrint`of `instanceOne` therefore with its own `str` ("Hi")

PS: you can do that in most langage but no-one does.